# DisplayMessageActivity.java file tutorial issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i'm starting to learn how to make android application by following the tutorial on their developer page. I'm trying to make a new DisplayMessageActivity class.
this is the tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#CreateActivity

My DisplayMessageActivity.java file contains by default this:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

while on their website it sais it should contain this :

```
    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() { }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                      container, false);
              return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

I have updated my eclipse to the latest version of ADT plugin and i still get this. When I try to paste their code to my DisplayMessageActivity.java file i get these errors:

> activity_display_message cannot be resolved or is not a field
>
> The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not
>   applicable for the   arguments (int,
>   DisplayMessageActivity.PlaceholderFragment)
>
> fragment_display_message cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score 0):

Both of your references in the code should be to R.layout.activity_display_message, although I do not get any errors there (make sure you followed all the steps in the tutorial). But I am following the same tutorial and am getting the same error with the add method and cannot figure out why.